# Deserialization json where value is in brackets square

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

How can I deserialize Json to an object. My Json:

```
...
"removed":
{
"series": [5],
"unit": [6,8]
}
```

My model:

```
public class ResultJson
{

    public int[] series { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, int> unit { get; set; }
}
```

but I get a error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type '' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>   
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
>   
> Path 'removed.series'

Comment: `unit` is an array. not a dictionary

Answer (score 1):

`Dictionary<int,int>` is expecting two numbers per item, use the following JSON format...

```
{
  "series": [5],
  "unit": {6:8}
}
```

If you need multiple items in the dictionary, use the format `{6:8,9:10}`

Otherwise just use a `List<int>` as you have with `series`

---

My recommendation on things like this is to reverse the code... instead of guessing what format the JSON needs to be in, create an instance of your object, fill it with data, then serialise it into JSON and see what it produces.

Comment: Agreed.  Also, this site will save you a great deal of headache:

http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: @Wesley - What a great little site!  Although it doesn't generate a dictionary object ;-)

Comment: I hadn't noticed that, before.  It seems that the JSON format is a bit ambiguous, there, so it is seen as an object type.  Easily overcome if you look at this:  https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDictionary.htm

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the unit property. That should be array, not Dictionary.

Refer this [Serialise into array](https://dotnetfiddle.net/npzcP1) and [Serialise into dictionary](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fZO2ac)

**Combination 1**

```
"{"series": [5],"unit": {6:8}}"

public class ResultJson
{
    public int[] series { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, int> unit { get; set; }
}
```

**Combination 2**

```
"{"series": [5],"unit": [6,8]}"

public class ResultJson
{
    public int[] series { get; set; }
    public int[] unit { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: the system throws the error into the series. If I put the attribute on the 'JsonIgnore' dictionary, the error also occurs

Comment: How do you know the OP doesn't need it to be a Dictionary?

Comment: @freefaller The format of the value is not a key value pair, they are just values. Dictionary would work with key value pairs.

Comment: @user2881533 Updated my answer with fiddle links. Have a look

Comment: But you're assuming that the JSON is correct and the model is incorrect.  What if the model is correct, but the OP is trying to find the correct format for the JSON?

Comment: @freefaller That is what the answer is. Based on the JSON he is receiving, that will fit into an array. Not a dictionary.

Comment: @user2881533 Updated the answer with 2 scenarios. Either you change your json if you control it. If you do not, you need to change the class structure.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
public partial class Test
{
    [JsonProperty("removed")]
    public Removed Removed { get; set; }
}

public partial class Removed
{
    [JsonProperty("series")]
    public List<long> Series { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("unit")]
    public List<long> Unit { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You may check this answer as the correct solution if it worked.